# Test inverse correlation of grouped data

Tags: r, correlation, mixed-model

I have data on word frequencies (column `f_0`) in speech turns (`Turnid`), pupil sizes during these turns (`pp_0`); the turns are grouped in terms of number of words they contain (column `size`). I hypothesize that `f_0` and `pp_0` are inversely correlated. How can I test this hypothesis?

My hunch is that a mixed-effects model is required to control for `size` (which would perhaps best be considered a fixed effect) but am unsure as to how to run the test.

**EDIT**:

Is this the right way to go?

```
library(lme4)
# Fit the mixed-effects model

model <- lmer(pp_0 ~ f_0 + Turnid +(1 | size), data = F_PP)
Warning message:
Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling
```

If this is the right way to define the model, waht does the summary output (**for my actual data, not just the data in `df`**) mean? How can it be interpreted? Does it support the hypothesis?

```
# Check the model summary
summary(model)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: pp_0 ~ f_0 + Turnid + (1 | size)
   Data: F_PP

REML criterion at convergence: 2453971

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-20.5629  -0.1791  -0.0117   0.1804  21.3419 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 size     (Intercept)    273.2  16.53  
 Residual             194249.0 440.74  
Number of obs: 163432, groups:  size, 23

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) 12.2150152  4.1253068   2.961
f_0          0.0013172  0.0003139   4.196
Turnid      -0.0003027  0.0002107  -1.437

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
       (Intr) f_0   
f_0     0.116       
Turnid -0.465 -0.052
fit warnings:
Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Turnid = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 52L, 52L, 
52L, 52L, 52L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 
74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 78L, 78L, 
78L, 78L, 78L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 
83L, 83L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 89L, 
89L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 
96L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 
99L, 99L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 
105L, 105L, 105L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 122L, 122L, 
122L, 122L, 122L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 132L, 132L, 132L, 
132L, 132L, 132L, 132L, 134L, 134L, 134L, 134L, 134L, 137L, 137L, 
137L), f_0 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -305L, -302L, 0L, -4932L, -5898L, 
-5969L, -4342L, -5412L, -5165L, 0L, -657L, 3517L, -693L, -813L, 
-847L, -693L, 0L, -1660L, 6367L, -2160L, -2221L, 0L, -8534L, 
-8077L, -7727L, -8113L, 0L, -7004L, -6211L, -8563L, -8077L, -7727L, 
-8295L, 0L, 828L, -190L, -368L, -14L, 0L, 2713L, 2155L, 0L, 23L, 
-5L, 0L, -7655L, -4982L, 0L, -693L, 1530L, -314L, 1402L, -467L, 
1439L, 0L, 2845L, -938L, 0L, 2611L, -5044L, -2371L, -5730L, 0L, 
-8624L, -7471L, 0L, 92L, -784L, 3609L, -576L, 0L, -54L, -170L, 
0L, -7879L, -8572L, 0L, -4245L, -3472L, 0L, 3015L, -521L, 0L, 
85L, 242L, 5823L, 37L, 23L, 1161L, 0L, 1340L, -141L, 1198L, 238L, 
-342L, -336L, 0L, -1481L, -1679L, 2143L, -1681L, 0L, 839L, 1108L, 
12L, 1041L, 0L, 1511L, -5L, 555L, 250L, -2L, -27L, 0L, -7095L, 
-8547L, -8634L, -6625L, -2928L, -8558L, 0L, 2218L, -2327L, 0L, 
-1082L, 711L, -993L, -1134L, 0L, 5928L, -95L, 0L, -575L, -1632L, 
0L, 6998L, -1275L, 0L, -19L, 992L, 1L, 30L, 133L, 15L, 0L, -3472L, 
-758L, 0L, -317L, -317L, -5684L, -4179L, 0L, 696L, 2914L, 0L, 
-3645L, -3823L, 0L, 103L, -50L, 0L, -574L, -1178L, 0L, 172L, 
-3598L, 0L, 6023L, 1681L, 0L, -5982L, -4139L, -3695L, -2159L, 
0L, -7996L, -6618L, -7527L, -8635L, 0L, 799L, 8415L, -54L, 86L, 
987L, -217L, 0L, 1468L, 3686L, -645L, -687L, 0L, 0L, 0L), pp_0 = c(0, 
-10.2489999999999, -76.742, 0, -84.3345, -52.9315, 0, -86.1054999999999, 
-202.575, -345.8325, -365.4495, -111.11, -283.1155, 0, -74.1494999999999, 
113.13, -24.8049999999998, -226.261, -150.2925, -65.6869999999999, 
0, 211.1485, 283.7575, 293.5085, 298.5055, 0, -3.16000000000008, 
-20.6205, -26.8615000000001, -23.2415000000001, 0, -24.9465, 
-11.634, 28.2910000000001, -12.6045, 16.0475, 9.73900000000003, 
0, -512.149, 160.531, 193.6885, 100.648, 0, 43.2165, 27.6395, 
0, -60.3140000000001, -48.638, 0, -144.267, -86.039, 0, 0.774499999999989, 
-6.91149999999993, 11.1030000000001, -242.4975, -1032.6445, 11.5074999999999, 
0, 83.5169999999999, -323.5835, 0, 154.5645, 185.205, 195.114, 
138.33, 0, -28.8835000000001, -77.9325000000001, 0, 6.3195, 23.904, 
38.377, 48.04, 0, 68.8395, -26.1135, 0, 89.5195, 255.0685, 0, 
-43.836, 19.4335, 0, 1.16800000000001, -485.191, 0, 481.2175, 
388.632, 388.112, 401.2195, 399.2115, 419.231, 0, 463.162, 526.033, 
430.1505, 446.2375, 492.2975, 513.056, 0, 56.345, 113.49, 113.5155, 
13.1170000000001, 0, 77.8774999999999, -161.1495, -146.4085, 
-42.6850000000001, 0, -11.521, -3.27750000000003, 55.6655000000001, 
175.6055, 251.2075, 297.9085, 0, 57.3505, 100.587, -46.7595, 
70.2015, -47.6215, -56.2139999999999, 0, -174.103, -144.221, 
0, 27.5314999999999, 73.886, 45.2545, 91.1875, 0, -173.5105, 
-227.9105, 0, 9.3195, -8.06299999999999, 0, -553.3095, 8.58849999999995, 
0, -128.128, -159.1975, -15.4515, 52.7515, 10.034, 14.779, 0, 
14.4200000000001, 52.1495, 0, 189.742166666667, -413.083833333333, 
320.036666666667, 392.994166666667, 0, -11.6709999999998, 36.393, 
0, -40.0230000000001, -14.4065, 0, -69.534, -79.6719999999999, 
0, -38.3870000000001, 13.0965, 0, -2.3694999999999, -30.6329999999999, 
0, -1.24400000000003, -24.101, 0, -471.8995, -61.6135000000002, 
-2.09300000000007, -41.8605, 0, 388.6835, 365.561, 321.0135, 
300.5315, 0, 11.213, -36.5010000000001, -103.36, -158.2555, -192.485, 
-172.593, 0, -411.262, -48.3770000000001, -41.6995000000001, 
-40.2965, 0, 140.4955, 139.6195), size = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
3L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, -199L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: This is essentially a "how to set up a particular statistical analysis" and how to interpret the results of a particular bit of analysis whose code runs without error. As such it's not really about coding but rather about statistical analysis and application and should be migrated to the StackExchange site that handles such questions.. It could be improved by a bit more explanation of the subject matter and what is known about the experimental setup, but